# Get ClaimsPrincipal from usermanager

Tags: asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

In a ASP.NET Core Controller I can Access `User` to get all current user claims as `ClaimsPrincipal`. Now I added a new user using `userManager.CreateAsync`, added some claims and need all his claims as a ClaimsPrincipal for some other function.
I tried the following:

```
  var user1 = new IdentityUserEntity
  {
// set username and stuff
  };
  var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user1, passwort);
  await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user1, new System.Security.Claims.Claim(MyClaimTypes.Stuff, MyClaimValues.Whatever));
```

afterwards I created a ClaimsPrincipal like this:

```
  var user1cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user1)));
```

Problem is, this ClaimsPrincipal does not contain the NameIdentifier (and maybe other stuff?).

How do I get a complete ClaimsPrincipal from a user I freshy added to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `CreateUserPrincipalAsync` method of `SignInManager`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a <see cref="ClaimsPrincipal"/> for the specified <paramref name="user"/>, as an asynchronous operation.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="user">The user to create a <see cref="ClaimsPrincipal"/> for.</param>
/// <returns>The task object representing the asynchronous operation, containing the ClaimsPrincipal for the specified user.</returns>
public virtual async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser user) => await ClaimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
```